# Using sed to split a string with a delimiter

Tags: linux, bash, sed, split

I have a string in the following format:

`string1:string2:string3:string4:string5`

I'm trying to use `sed` to split the string on `:` and print each sub-string on a new line.  Here is what I'm doing:

`cat ~/Desktop/myfile.txt | sed s/:/\\n/`

This prints:

```
string1
string2:string3:string4:string5
```

How can I get it to split on each delimiter?

Comment: You could consider `tr : '\n' <~/Desktop/myfile.txt`.  Since `sed` can open files quite happily, you don't need to use `cat` in your example from the question.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

To split a string with a delimiter with GNU sed you say:

```
sed 's/delimiter/\n/g'     # GNU sed
```

For example, to split using `:` as a delimiter:

```
$ sed 's/:/\n/g' <<< "he:llo:you"
he
llo
you
```

Or with a non-GNU sed:

```
$ sed $'s/:/\\\n/g' <<< "he:llo:you"
he
llo
you
```

---

In this particular case, you missed the `g` after the substitution. Hence, it is just done once. See:

```
$ echo "string1:string2:string3:string4:string5" | sed s/:/\\n/g
string1
string2
string3
string4
string5
```

`g` stands for `g`lobal and means that the substitution has to be done globally, that is, for any occurrence. See that the default is 1 and if you put for example 2, it is done 2 times, etc.

All together, in your case you would need to use:

```
sed 's/:/\\n/g' ~/Desktop/myfile.txt
```

Note that you can directly use the `sed ... file` syntax, instead of unnecessary piping: `cat file | sed`.

Comment: Damnit!  I was so close.  What does the `g` do?  And I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.  Thanks!

Comment: It stands for `global` and means that the substitution has to be done `globally`, that is, for any ocurrence. See that the default is 1 and if you put for example 2, it is done 2 times, etc.

Comment: This doesn't work in non-GNU sed. The canonical/portable way to do, say, your last example would be `sed $'s/:/\\\n/g' file.txt`, relying on bash format quoting to interpret the ANSI backslash notation.

Comment: @ghoti thanks, I have updated with this approach also. In the future, feel free to update posts to make them more correct, we all learn from it!

Answer (score 35):

Using `\n` in `sed` is non-portable. The portable way to do what you want with `sed` is:

```bash
sed 's/:/\
/g' ~/Desktop/myfile.txt
```

but in reality this isn't a job for `sed` anyway, it's the job `tr` was created to do:

```bash
tr ':' '
' < ~/Desktop/myfile.txt
```

Comment: On iTerm, on MacOS, the endline character can be done on the input using `alt+enter`. Handy trick for splitting `$PATH` variable btw.

Answer (score 25):

Using simply [tr](/questions/tagged/tr) :

```
$ tr ':' $'\n' <<< string1:string2:string3:string4:string5
string1
string2
string3
string4
string5
```

If you really need [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) :

```
$ sed 's/:/\n/g' <<< string1:string2:string3:string4:string5
string1
string2
string3
string4
string5
```

Comment: Liked the solution using tr. Simple and handy. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'y/:/\n/' file
```

or perhaps:

```
sed y/:/$"\n"/ file
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
cat ~/Desktop/myfile.txt | sed s/:/\\n/g
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using gnu sed then you can use `\x0A` for newline:

```
sed 's/:/\x0A/g' ~/Desktop/myfile.txt
```

Comment: Not necessarily. Win32 environments will use a different newline character, and last I checked, Cygwin uses gnu sed.