# Split string by delimiter and print elements on new line

Tags: regex, bash, macos, sed

I'm not replicating the behaviour of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18234407/1156245) on Mac.  I want split elements each on their own line.  Any idea?

```
$ echo "string1:string2:string3:string4:string5" | sed s/:/\\n/g
string1nstring2nstring3nstring4nstring5
```

Comment: Possibly. I can't tell because the answer is too long for a mere mortal to read in a single lifetime

Comment: The linked answer is not that long and it is many alternatives for the same thing. You only need one to work.

Comment: That said don't use `sed` and this is easier. `echo '....' | tr : \\n`

Comment: Funny but I can't actually see the answer below anywhere on that page..

Comment: The answer here is the **first** alternative (the one marked `(a)`) in the linked answer.

Comment: `sed 's/two/& new\` is not the same as the answer below.

Comment: @etan-reisner that `tr` option is useful tx.

Comment: No, the `&` isn't but that was about the other persons specific goal. The backslash before literal newline to add a newline **is** and that's the point. Since that was your question and that's what the alternative below does. The first example below is new though. Though my `tr` option is also in the linked question.

Comment: Other dupe question doesn't address splitting by delimiter part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On OSX this should work using `bash`:

```
s="string1:string2:string3:string4:string5"
echo "${s//:/$'\n'}"
string1
string2
string3
string4
string5
```

Or using `sed`:

```
echo "string1:string2:string3:string4:string5" | sed $'s/:/\\\n/g'

string1
string2
string3
string4
string5
```

**Alternatively** this should also work with OSX `sed`:

```
echo "string1:string2:string3:string4:string5" | sed 's/:/\
/g'

string1
string2
string3
string4
string5
```

Or using `tr`:

```
echo "string1:string2:string3:string4:string5" | tr : '\n'
```