# Split string with literal \n in a for loop

Tags: bash, shell

Please consider this string: `foo\nbar\nbaz`

How can I split it using \n as delimiter?

I have played with IFS without luck.

**EDIT: I want to split it inside a for loop.**

Ok, I'll explain what my situation is.

I need to feed a certain config file using data stored in a MySQL database.

I get the value from a TEXT type column. Each record in this column could be empty or multiple email address (foo@bar.tld), domain names (bar.tld), or placeholders for domain names including its subdomains (.bar.tld).

By design, the programmer decided this field should be multiline, hence the separator.

My job is to get those values individualy and proccess them. So I iterate over the values and do some things to them.

The REAL problem IS I'm getting a two bytes separator char just like this:

`foo@bar.tld\nfoo.tld\n.foo.tld`
So I can't access each element individually.

I hope you can understand now (English is not my native language).

**EDIT2:**

Right now I'm solving the issue with this code:

```
PERMITTED_SENDERS="foo@bar.tld\nfoo.tld\n.foo.tld"

for SENDER in ${PERMITTED_SENDERS//'\n'/ }
do
    if [[ "$SENDER" =~ @ ]]
    then
        printf "\tsender == $SENDER\n"
    elif [[ "$SENDER" =~ ^\. ]]
    then
        printf "\tsender =~ [@|.]$(to_tld_domain $SENDER)\$\n"
    else
        printf "\tsender =~ \@$(to_regex $SENDER)\$\n"
    fi
done
```

@CharlesDuffy is the `for` loop still bad to solve this?

**EDIT3**

After reading mysql help thoroughly I ended passing `-r` to `mysql` command to get the results in raw format.

Now I have this:

```
while IFS='' read -r permitted_sender
do
    # Do stuff
done <<<"$permitted_senders"
```

Comment: Does that string contain 11 characters or 13?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using sed to split a string with a delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234378/using-sed-to-split-a-string-with-a-delimiter)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin it could be any lenght. I don't want to use `sed` here.

Comment: `var=foo\nbar\nbaz; for word in $(printf ${var//\n/\\n}); do echo $word; done`? (of course `printf ${var//\n/\\n})` is doing the splitting, wrapping in the `for` just gives you access to each in the variable `word`)

Comment: literal `\n`, two characters, not a single literal newline character? And to be clear, this is something you **shouldn't** want to do. It'll be buggy.

Comment: @oneohthree, the thing David was asking is whether `\n` is one character or two (thus, if the total string length counted each `\n` as two characters), not if your code would only **ever** handle 11 or 13-character strings.

Comment: I'm getting the values from some database, I can't change this.

Comment: @oneohthree, ...the details of which database it is, then, matter. If it's generating format sequences that `printf '%b' "$var"` will make literal (ie. if it's two characters now but you *want* it to be one character), that provides a preprocessing step that'll make your life and job easier.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That was chepner, and it is a very good question. Though hard to see how it could be 11 unless the string was printed in some wonky editor that inserts literals.

Comment: BTW, consider running `printf '%q\n' "$var"` and providing its output -- that'll make the literal-vs-syntactic question clear.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Sadly it doesn't work.

Comment: Even if that code *did* work it'd be buggy. If you had an element containing only a `*` character in the output, for instance, that would get replaced with a list of files in the current directory. Relying on string-splitting is evil, which is why I'm arguing against using `for` here at all.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, *grumble* re: quoting exactly the wrong thing there. (And I'd actually rather get `printf '%q\n' "$var"`, *exactly* like that -- no string-splitting, no quoting, no manipulation -- if the goal is to find out what the OP's *actual* input is).

Comment: Duh..... More coffee... This is just a hornets nest of pitfalls. That's why my first thought was escaping the literal `\n` and passing though `printf` came to mind. I don't know why the OP had difficulty with it. Separated fine with just `var=foo\nbar\nbaz; printf ${var//\n/\\n}`, but it is no panacea.

Comment: @ap, I'm not sure I see that as a pertinent dupe. The OP here is trying to iterate over pieces, not split them one-to-a-line.

Comment: That's where the original `var=foo\nbar\nbaz; for word in $(printf ${var//\n/\\n}); do echo $word; done` came in, it just failed for lack of single quoting the assignment to `var` on his setup. single quoted, `printf "%b" "$var"` works well, but would still have the side effects of catching `tabs`, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think that was edited in after the flag. Can I remove it or is it just what it is now?

Comment: You're right -- that was edited in later. Since there weren't any answers yet, the edit's legit -- though I'm not sure the question is worth a reopen vote in its current state. (Maybe if it were generalized how to iterate over pieces of a string, split on a multi-byte sequence?)

Comment: Yes, a `for` loop is still the wrong tool for the job as currently written. If you wanted to avoid the problems (glob expansion, etc), split it into two steps: `IFS=' ' read -r -a senders <<<"${PERMITTED_SENDERS//'\n'/ }"` to read your string into an array, and `for sender in "${senders[@]]"; do ...` to iterate over elements in that array.

Comment: And note the lower-case variable names -- that's intentional. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph: All-uppercase names are used for variables with meaning to the operating system or shell, whereas lowercase names are reserved for application use and guaranteed not to conflict with names meaningful to the system. (Also note that setting a regular shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable, so naming conventions necessarily apply in both places).

Answer (score 4):

A `for` loop is the wrong tool for this job. Consider a `while` loop instead:

```
str='foo\nbar\nbaz'

while [[ $str ]]; do            # iterate as long as we have input
  if [[ $str = *'\n'* ]]; then  # if there's a '\n' sequence later...
    first=${str%%'\n'*}         #   put everything before it into 'first'
    rest=${str#*'\n'}           #   and put everything after it in 'rest'
  else                          # if there's no '\n' later...
    first=$str                  #   then put the whole rest of the string in 'first'
    rest=''                     #   and there is no 'rest'
  fi
  echo "Processing piece: $first"
  str=$rest
done
```

This properly emits:

```
Processing piece: foo
Processing piece: bar
Processing piece: baz
```

---

That said, if you *must* use a `for` loop:

```
str='foo\nbar\nbaz'
set -f                                        # disable globbing
printf -v str_literal '%b' "$str"             # replace '\n' with a literal newline
IFS=$'\n' read -r -a pieces <<<"$str_literal" # split on literal newlines
for piece in "${pieces[@]}"; do               # iterate over the pieces
  echo "Processing piece: $piece"
done
```

Note that this is not without side effects -- it will replace `\t` sequences with literal tabs, for instance. I'm *assuming* that that's what you actually want, since your data store is using `\n` to refer to newlines.

Comment: Such a big effort to address this, I really feel embarrased (DAMN).

Comment: Don't be, while this isn't exactly a 'corner case', it isn't a run of the mill case either. The set up, and the quoting of your string is important on all that follows. Glad to have Charles handy... `:)`

Comment: I came up doing this in order to avoid this mess: `SELECT REPLACE(thecolumn,'\n',' ')`

Comment: If *that's* all you wanted, it would just be one line of bash: `str=${str//'\n'/ }`

Comment: However, again, `for item in $string` is buggy unless you run `set -f` before it. See [Don't Read Lines With `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) -- granted, you're iterating over fields, but much (even though not all) of the reasoning still applies.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, input should be clean.

Comment: I like this approach better: > it would just be one line of bash: `str=${str//'\n'/ }`

Comment: @oneohthree, *nod* -- it's not an answer to your question, because it doesn't answer *what you actually asked*, but if what you need and what you asked differ... well, there we are.